# NodeJS and file package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I'm just approaching node-js, I wanted to know what the difference is between the files

```
package.json
package-lock.json
```

Finally I wanted to know if it exists in addition to the command nmp install to install the various dependencies a command to make the build / dist to be able to deploy on other machines

a command similar to maven install that creates the .jar file of my Java application.

Thanks

Comment: [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json), [package-lock.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json)

Answer (score 0):

The basic part of Node Package Management (NPM) is Command Line Interface (CLI) that work in all situation.

#### A)

A Node.js base project initialize when

```
 $ npm init
```

In this moment package.json generated automatically with minimized key/value data. some feature like **name, version, keywords, description**

#### B)

If you need any dependency for inject in project, with command line

```
$ npm install --save express
```

add it to local **node_module** folder.

*Notice:* in

```
--save
```

flag dependency install locally.

#### C)

All dependency that store in your **node_modules** indexed in ***package-lock.json*** file that shows available package in **node_modules**.

> In fact ***package-lock.json*** containe more detaile like:
>
> - resolved: the source of library URL like *https://registry.npmjs.org/@sailshq/connect-redis/-/connect-redis-3.2.1.tgz*
> - requires: all dependency that install for this package.
> - integrity: hashed data